# Accessing each element inside a div individually with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping site where all the info is inside a div. Most of the elements inside do not have a unique identifier which has me stumped on how to pull all the info out individually. Here is the html I am working with

```
<div class="message-userExtras">
            
    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Joined</dt>
    <dd>Feb 23, 2023</dd>
    </dl>


    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Messages</dt>
    <dd>22</dd>
    </dl>

    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Reaction score</dt>
    <dd>
    <a href="/members/297754/reactions-info" class="link">18</a>
    </dd>
    </dl>
                    
                                        
    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Escrow deals</dt>
    <dd>3</dd>
    </dl>
                    

    <dl class="pairs pairs--justified">
    <dt>Deposit</dt>
    <dd><a class="deposit-button" href="/members/297754/deposit" data-xf-click="overlay">0.1 <i class="fa--xf fab fa-btc deposit-fa-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></dd>
    </dl>

</div>
```

An example of the formatted info would be:

> 'joined': ['Feb 23, 2023'], 'messages': ['22'], 'reaction score': ['18'], 'escrow deals': ['3'], 'deposit': ['0.1']}

Help on how to access these elements individually would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try out this solution for python**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("your_page_url_here")

xpath_expression = "//div[@class='message-userExtras']//dl[@class='pairs pairs--justified']/*"

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_expression)

results = {}

for element in elements:
    tag_name = element.tag_name
    text = element.text.strip()
    if tag_name == "dt":
        key = text
    elif tag_name == "dd":
        results[key] = text

for key, value in results.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution where I iterate through all the **`dl`** elements and then extract **`dt`** and **`dd`** to create the dictionary in the format you're looking for.

For data extraction tasks, I have used [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) due to its simplicity and effectiveness. However, there are many tools like [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) that are also excellent for different scraping scenarios. The choice of tool really depends on the specific problem and individual preferences.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "example_page"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

pairs = soup.select("div.message-userExtras dl")
elements = {}

for pair in pairs:
    key = pair.dt.text.strip().lower()
    if pair.dd.text:
        value = pair.dd.text.strip()
    else:
        value = pair.dd.a.text.strip()
    elements[key] = value

for key, value in elements.items():
    print(f"'{key}': ['{value}']", end=',')

print()
```

Output:

```
'joined': ['Feb 23, 2023'],'messages': ['22'],'reaction score': ['18'],'escrow deals': ['3'],'deposit': ['0.1']
```

It's important to choose the tool that best fits your needs. In my work, using these tools appropriately can make a significant difference. Familiarizing yourself with various options and finding the one that you feel most comfortable with is key.